# How to download latest XML file from our website securely?

Tags: c#, .net, download

We're writing a console app which is to be installed on client's machines. It's possible we'll want to update an XML file used by the app. **How can I ensure the file is downloaded safely from our servers, eg no malicious files instead?**

I presume the app would call our API to get the latest version number. If its newer than what it has, it would download this XML file from the specified URL. However doesn't this make it vulnerable to man in the middle attacks or similar? I want to ensure our app is not responsible for downloading a malicious file (eg could be a malicious exe file).

Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign the XML file with a private key on your server, then verify it on the client with a public key embedded in your app.

This will only help if you have a secure mechanism to deliver the initial app with its public key (eg, HTTPS)

Comment: Thanks - that will ensure the file hasn't changed. However that doesn't stop a malicious file being downloaded, does it?
Would downloading over HTTPS make it fine?
Then I guess the only vulnerability is spoofing our server through a DNS attack?

Comment: @IgorK: If the hash doesn't match, you can just reject and delete the file and no harm will have been done.  HTTPS (with a signed certificate) will prevent DNS and MITM issues, but will not prevent an attacker from modifying the file on the server through other means.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not sure I agree, doesn't the file have to be downloaded to check the hash? I thought some viruses can auto execute as soon as they're on the system?

Comment: @IgorK: Wrong; a virus can only run if the file is viewed or opened by a program with a vulnerability.

Comment: @Slaks Thanks for putting my mind at rest! I guess checking the hash off the file doesn't count as viewing or opening then.

Comment: @IgorK: As long as your code (including the hashing function) does not contain any security vulnerabilities, you're fine.

Comment: There's no need need to specifically sign the file when it's downloaded over https as the https connection also provides integrity of the data being transfered (it wouldn't be very useful without that). Also when a hacker has access to the server containing the file you should probably worry about access to the private key as well. If the private key is compromised you're screwed, so the server must be secure.

Comment: @AVee: Wrong; HTTPS does not guarantee that an attacker has not modified the file on the server through other means (eg, compromised FTP login)

Comment: See above, if the server is compromised you probably have bigger issues.

Comment: @AVee: True, although that depends on where the file is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Serve the file over https and make sure the client checks the certificate. That way you're sure the file comes from the correct server and is not changed somewhere on the line. Assuming you keep your server secure that should be enough to be sure you get the correct file.